# How to get tpope/vim-rails gf command to work with SpaceVim

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-ruby, spacevim

I am using SpaceVim as Ruby on Rails IDE and installed the tpope/vim-rails plugin.

Commands such as `:Econtroller`, `:Emodel` and `:find` are working just fine, but the `gf` command provided by this plugin is not working in SpaceVim.

When I try to use it, it shows me an error message such as the ones below:

```
# for partial
Can't find file "users/edit_form" in path

# with association
User has_many :notes
Can't find file "notes" in path
```

Comment: Does it work with regular vim?

Comment: Yes it works with regular vim. Also `gf` works with sass partial, but is not working for the view template. If I rename the partial name i.e. `render partial: 'partial_1'` to `render partial: '_partial_1'` then also `gf` works.

Comment: You need to make sure `path` is set right: check with `:verbose set path?`

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem.
It seems that SpaceVim overrides the `gf` command in some way so that `rails-vim` plugin's `gf` doesn't check for `_` on partial names anymore.
Also, you have to be on the partial name itself (instead of anywhere on the same line, thanks to `vim-ruby` plugin) for `gf` to work. So maybe it messes with `vim-ruby` too.

Comment: What does `:map gf` show you in SpaceVim?

Comment: with `:verbose map gf` on spacevim, I get
`n  gf            gf
        Last set from ~/.SpaceVim/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim line 50
`.
So clearly, SpaceVim resets the gf command. I tried to comment this line; also tried to replace this line by the gf fuction from `vim-ruby` (but it's not  supposed to work that way apparently)

Comment: With a regular setup (with vim-ruby), `map gf` gives me `n   gf   @<SNR>118_c:find <Plug><cfile><CR>`

Comment: If I delete everything inside `.SpaceVim/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim`, leaving only `let g:_spacevim_mappings_g = {}`, then the `gf` command works as expected.
But I have no idea how to tweak SpaceVim's `g` command

Comment: Actually, just deleting `nmap g [G]` (line 6) and `nmap gf gf` (line 50) inside `.SpaceVim/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim` allows `gf` to work again.
But then I lose the `g` SpaceVim menu (which I could still get with `[G]`.

Comment: Thanks for your testing and your comments @Tim! It really helped me understand what was going on here! I wrote [an answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25223/18609) with my findings and I'll try to send a PR to vim-rails to get it to work inside SpaceVim, let's see if I can help fix that! Cheers again!

Comment: Wow awesome! Thank you, your answer answered so many questions I had

Comment: I sent a PR to tpope. If you use `filbranden/vim-rails` as a plug-in, you should get a version that works with SpaceVim now!

Comment: awesooooooooooooooome, I'll check your PR to understand more how vim works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

vim-rails implements the `gf` key-binding by adding a mapping for it.

But it will [only add a mapping for `gf`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/master/autoload/rails.vim#L4827-L4829) if it detects it wasn't mapped before, or if a previous mapping for `gf` matches a regex including `_gf(v:count`, `Ruby` or `Rails` (presumably because it's overriding known mappings from other related plug-ins by tpope such as vim-ruby or projectionist.)

The code snippet is:

```
let pattern = '^$\|_gf(v:count\|[Rr]uby\|[Rr]ails'
if mapcheck('gf', 'n') =~# pattern
  nmap <buffer><silent> gf         <SID>:find <Plug><cfile><CR>
```

On the other hand, SpaceVim defines [a mapping for `gf`](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/v1.4.0/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim#L50):

```
nnoremap gf gf
```

It's an odd mapping that just maps it to itself... (Not sure why SpaceVim wants such a mapping, since it doesn't seem to do anything, just maps the command to itself. I just posted [a follow up question about these odd mappings](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25224/18609).)

*If* it was installed, the `gf` mapping from vim-rails *would* supercede the mapping from SpaceVim.

But since vim-rails checks first, it finds the mapping from SpaceVim, which doesn't match its regex of expected mappings to override, it never really *installs* its `gf` key-binding, which causes the problem as reported here.

(Simply dropping the `nnoremap gf gf` is not enough, since the used `mapcheck()` will match prefixes and SpaceVim also creates a [mapping for `g` by itself](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/v1.4.0/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim#L11), so that mapping breaks the checks as well.)

Even though this issue seems to be triggered by the odd set of mappings created by SpaceVim, perhaps the easiest fix here would be to fix vim-rails to also install its `gf` key-binding if it finds the SpaceVim one, simply by adding a straight `^gf$` to the list of mappings to replace in its `mapcheck()`.

**UPDATE:** I sent out [PR #558](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/pull/558) to suggest this change to vim-rails. Tested it on SpaceVim and it worked for me as expected.

**UPDATE 2:** The PR was merged upstream by tpope, so latest vim-rails should now work fine with SpaceVim!

Answer (score -1):

You  can check `:map gf`, it will tell you what this key is mapped to.

Comment: I think the problem is not what `gf` is mapped to since the command executed seems to be the correct one, the issue is that the command doesn't open the right files.

Comment: Yes the `gf` is working as expected for `scss partials` but is not working for `html partial` and association with `has_many` e.g. `has_many :users`, but works with `has_one :user`

Comment: Hi @WangShidong, I spent some time looking into this one and wrote [an answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25223/18609) with my findings. I'll try to send a PR to vim-rails to make it work with SpaceVim. I'm puzzled about the `nnoremap gf gf` mapping in SpaceVim and I posted a [follow up question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25224) about it, maybe I can get your attention there? Thanks!