# Why would you use `nnoremap gf gf` as SpaceVim does?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, spacevim

While writing [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25223/18609) about vim-rails on SpaceVim, I found out these mappings set by SpaceVim, such as [this one](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/v1.4.0/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim#L50):

```
nnoremap gf gf
```

SpaceVim also creates similar mappings for all of the other `gX` commands and all [`zX` commands](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/v1.4.0/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/z.vim) as well.

Which made me wonder: **Why would you need such mappings?**

As far as I can tell, they don't actually *do* anything. They just map a key sequence to itself, so they'll simply have Vim execute the exact same command as if the mappings were not there. (Or am I wrong about that and there's a subtle difference when such a trivial mapping is actually installed?)

I *suspect* they have something to do with the [leader guide](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/v1.4.0/autoload/SpaceVim/mapping/g.vim#L10-L11) for the `g` (and `z`) commands, but I still don't understand why they're needed.

Can someone familiar with SpaceVim (implementation) or with this particular code pattern please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can make a guess (but I have never seen this before either, and I haven't used SpaceVim yet) based on this issue: [gq for reformatting doesn't work #787](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues/787). `nmap g [G]` essentially blocks all the usual normal-mode commands that start `g`. `gq`, for example, is now `[G]q`.

`nnoremap gf gf`, by virtue of being a `noremap` version, blocks further mapping expansion, so `gf` effectively remains a plain `gf`.

Answer (score 3):

I am author of SpaceVim. The main feature of spacevim is key binding guide. This feature need to run `:map <prefix>` to paser all mappings, and generate guide context. In vim, too many default key binding begin with `g`, most users include me do not remenber all of them. so I need the guide when I forgot next key after press g.

[image]